# Use metal as backend in skia

Tags: skia

I want to try the metal with skia, but the surface always returns `null`, and I can't find any way around..

Here is the code:

```
_device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
MTLTextureDescriptor* textureDst = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Unorm width:480 height:320 mipmapped:NO];
_texture = [_device newTextureWithDescriptor:textureDst];
_queue = [_device newCommandQueue];

auto context = (GrContext::MakeMetal((__bridge_retained void*)_device,
                                     (__bridge_retained void*)_queue));

GrMtlTextureInfo info;
info.fTexture = (__bridge_retained void*)_texture;
GrBackendRenderTarget target(480, 320, 1, info);

//sk_sp<SkColorSpace> colorSpace = SkColorSpace::MakeSRGB();
SkSurfaceProps props(SkSurfaceProps::kLegacyFontHost_InitType);
const SkImageInfo infos = SkImageInfo::Make(0, 0, kN32_SkColorType, kPremul_SkAlphaType);
sk_sp<SkSurface> 

surface(SkSurface::MakeFromBackendRenderTarget(context.get(), target, kBottomLeft_GrSurfaceOrigin,nullptr,&props);
```

The surface always create failed, returns null, the context and target is valid.
I've also tried another pixelformat, like `BGRA8888Unorm`, but it did not work.

Comment: Looks like you asked this on Skia-Discuss and got an answer, but I felt it's worth it to post the link here in case anyone else is trying metal backend in skia. The answer essentially is "use opengl" because metal backend is still being developed. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/skia-discuss/jCXgjOx0olA